# How to save TPOTClassifier to continue fitting after?

Tags: python, classification, genetic-programming, tpot

I'm fitting `TPOTClassifier` and it currently takes considerable time. Is it any possibility to store all the "population" and all the settings needed to have them loaded after and continue training further? What I read in the [documentation](https://rhiever.github.io/tpot/using) allows to store only the best "evolved" pipeline using `export` method:

```
tpot = TPOTClassifier(generations=5, population_size=50, verbosity=2)
tpot.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(tpot.score(X_test, y_test))
tpot.export('tpot_best_pipeline.py') # export the best pipeline among the population
```

Also I can limit a number of generations by passing `generations` argument in `TPOTClassifier` constructor as above, but how can I persist the classifier?

Comment: Have you tried to pickle the TPOTClassifier instance? Especially when combined with the `warm_start` feature, you should be able to pause the run partway through, pickle it, then load it back via pickle and pick up where you left off.